# Ошибка 404, Защита сайта не настроена! После переезда на новый домен

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, vds, vesta

Всем доброго времени суток, случилась неприятная ситуация, вынуждены были переехать на новый домен, но после переезда случились непонятки с SSL.

Сайт открывается с телефона через раз, с компьютера вообще не открывается, вылазит белая страница и на ней просто надпись: Защита сайта не настроена.

Сначала думали что стандартное получение ssl от vestacp глючит и что-то неправильно выписывает, но потом подключили CloudFlare и проблема осталась та же самая.

Когда в панель добавляю новый домен (до переноса файлов), то пустая страница от xenforo 404, появляется на www, но https так-же пишет "Защита сайта не настроена". Как только переношу файлы сайта, то www отваливается и больше не работает, идёт переадресация на https. В htaccess переадресация стоит только с http, но www, нигде не фигурирует.

VDS - CentOS 7.7.1908

Сайт: XenForo на VestaCP, nginx, php-fpm

Домен на beget: fantastic-projects.ru (не реклама)

Стоит привязка CloudFlare к домену.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]